# Symfony2 FOS assigning roles in the controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I am using FOS bundle and SonataUserBundle in my project. 
When a User registers in the form he selects the type of his account. Is he a buyer a seller or both. Depending on the selected choice he should be assigned to a different role.

This is the form field:

```
->add('type', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'form.label.type',
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => array(
                'buy' => 'Client',
                'sell' => 'Provider',
                'both' => 'Both'
                )
            ))
```

I overwrided the registrationcontroller and in the confirmedAction i did this:

```
public function confirmedAction()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $type = $user->container->getType();
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        if($type == 'buy') {
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_USER');
            $userManager->updateUser($user);
        }

        else if($type == 'sell') {
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_SONATA_PROVIDER');
            $userManager->updateUser($user);
        }
        else {
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_SONATA_PROVIDER', 'ROLE_USER');
            $userManager->updateUser($user);
        }

    }
```

However this does not assign a role to my newly created user. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you tried to see in which loop you are ( with an echo or a return ) ?

Comment: I think you're in the else and that you have to provide it in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about the configuration ( config.yml ) that had not the enable as true for confirmation,

see : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md for more informations

Answer (score 1):

I think that addRole is looking for an array, can you try :

```
...
addRole(array('ROLE_USER'));
...
addRole(array('ROLE_SONATA_PROVIDER'));
...
addRole(array('ROLE_SONATA_PROVIDER', 'ROLE_USER'));
...
```

Comment: This does not help. One thing is conserning me is that in the network tab I am getting a POST 302 when I am trying to register. I dont know if thats the case, but shouldnt it be 200?

Comment: Though I can see in the network tab that I am passing the forms data correctly

Comment: Mmmh so it doesn't work. Did you tried to do it as a normal entity (without the updateUser )

Comment: If you mean with persist and flush then yes I tried but it didnt work.

Comment: And you already tested about the user ( something like echo his username ) and about type ?

Comment: Can you try the inverse that I said? 

    
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_USER'); / 
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_SONATA_PROVIDER'); / 
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_SONATA_PROVIDER');
            $user->container->addRole('ROLE_USER');

Comment: Yes everything about the user works. Maybe This is not the right way to add a role on registration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82920/discussion-between-iblue-and-dominykas55).